# How do I authenticate with a GitHub app on behalf of a user using the device flow?

Tags: authentication, github-api

What I do ([the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-user-access-token-for-a-github-app#using-the-device-flow-to-generate-a-user-access-token)):

1. Create an app (https://github.com/settings/apps)

   - GitHub App name: `some-unique-name`
   - Homepage URL: https://example.com (yeah, example.com, because I only need access to GitHub API from CLI, any better ideas?)
   - check Enable Device Flow
   - uncheck Active in the Webhooks section
   - repository permissions: [Administration](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28#administration): read and write (which also adds [Metadata](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/permissions-required-for-github-apps?apiVersion=2022-11-28#metadata): read-only)
2. Log in

   ```
   $ curl -X POST \
   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
   'https://github.com/login/device/code?client_id=...'
   {"device_code":"...","user_code":"...","verification_uri":"https://github.com/login/device",...}

   // authorize the app at https://github.com/login/device

   $ curl -X POST \
   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
   'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=...&device_code=...&grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code'
   {"access_token":"...", ...}
   ```
3. Make a request

   ```
   $ curl -L -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
   -H 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
   -H 'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' \
   https://api.github.com/repos/x-yuri/test-pub-repo/keys
   {"message": "Resource not accessible by integration",...}

   $ curl -L -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' \
   -H 'Authorization: Bearer ...' \
   -H 'X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28' \
   https://api.github.com/repos/x-yuri/test-private-repo/keys
   {"message": "Not Found", ...}
   ```

I'm using my personal account (GitHub Free).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part was installing the GitHub app. Installing an app gives the app the permissions specified when creating the app. And the resulting permissions are [intersection](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-user-access-token-for-a-github-app) of the user's (who authorizes the app) and app's permissions:

> Similarly, a user access token can only access resources that both the user and app can access. For example, if an app is granted access to repository A and B, and the user can access repository B and C, the user access token can access repository B but not A or C.

A howto can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/9d4e7e9daa0ef3eaaf50fe8b017c16ba).